# Compare Database container and class container

Tags: c#, database, class

I am using a SQL Server database in my current project. I was watching the MVC Storefront videos (specifically the repository pattern) and I noticed that Rob (the creator of MVC Storefront) used a class called Category and Product, instead of a database and I have notice that using LINQ-SQL or ADO.NET, that a class is generated. Is there an advantage to using a class over a database to store information? Or is it the other way around? Or are they even comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case, the Category and Product classes are wrappers that persist their data to the database when something is changed. The [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) is a perfect example of that.

Answer (score 0):

A class is an object in .NET, a class may or may not contain methods for data access to a database. However they are not comparable or related.

Read hear about classes: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Introduction-to-Objects-and-Classes-in-C-Sharp-Part-2/